# Java перевод 4-х байтной HEX-строки в десятичное число

Tags: java, строки, hex, преобразование

Имеется строка числа `HexUtils.byteArrayToHexString(explicitXBeeMessage.getData()).substring(0,8)`
строку проверил, число выводится корректно
числа диапазона от 0 до FFFFFFFF, как число можно преобразовать 10-ю систему с возможностью постановки плавающей запятой. Варианты `Double.parseDouble()` и прочие - работают только на малых числах а-ля 0x0005

Answer (score 2):

Максимальное число в вашем диапазоне - `FFFFFFFF` равно в десятичной системе `4294967295`, оно не влезет в `Integer` в Java, но влезет в `Long`. По сути это максимальное беззнаковое 4-байтное целое число. Поскольку Java не умеет в беззнаковые, вам и нужно использовать `Long`.

Следующий код сумеет распарсить любое значение из вашего диапазона из переменной `hex`, далее вы просто можете его в double записать если нужно:

```
String hex = "FFFFFFFF";
System.out.println(Long.parseLong(hex, 16));
```

> 4294967295

Comment: Благодларю, помогло `(double)Long.parseLong(HexUtils.byteArrayToHexString(explicitXBeeMessage.getData()).substring(0,8),16)`

Answer (score 1):

А до кучи можно

```
    String hex = "FFFFFFFF";

    long l = Long.valueOf(hex, 16);

    BigInteger b = new BigInteger(hex, 16);
```